# Firebase Database modeling for iOS App?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-modeling

I'm trying to figure out how to create a very complex data model in Firebase database. The whole app is like a network. There are users with profiles, there are posts, comments, likes, reblogs, etc. 
Now, my goal is to outline my database before I start coding it all. But here's the thing - I know that the database should be (or it's advisable to be) as flat as possible, structure should be based on the views (`UIViewControllers`) and it should use referencing.

The thing is that it gets very complex, especially because there's not just 1 type of a post but 9 of them. Meaning - normal text post, video post, audio post, poll post, etc. And I'm not sure how to structure those, because each post would also have comments, likes, reblogs etc. Currently, I have a global Posts object that stores ALL types of posts, but based on the post type the user has created, it's stored into each specific post type. Then I reference that in the user object so I can easily pull them out and sort them by type. But I'm not convinced this is the right way to do it or if there's a better way. I'm starting to see some nesting and that's why I'm not sure.

Here's a screenshot of the database structure (it's easier to illustrate it that way):

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to recommend a JSON structure without knowing the use-case that you're trying to implement. Your current description is way too broad. Pretty much the only thing I can say is that your data is not flat enough. E.g. you're mixing user profile data (e.g. their name) with things like their likes and posts under `/Users`. To learn more about data modeling see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and view [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - this structure I learned from a Swift course and according to that developer (his name is Mark Price by the way), this is the way to go. He literally suggested that storing users' likes, postsID, etc should be referenced from the user's profile and gathered in a global Post object (array). Thanks for the links, I'll read the article and see the tutorials (i think i saw several of them before that)

Comment: It all depends on use-cases. A common use-case is creating a list of user profiles. In your data structure that requires that you also download all the users' likes, followers, etc. That's a waste of bandwidth if all you need is their profile information. Now if you never query `/Users` that may be fine. But we can't know that without seeing the use-case you're struggling with.